# Multiple ASP.NET clone sites accessing different Databases

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, session

I have a problem and need advice on how to start solving it.
I have made a an ASP.NET site with visual web Developer that use a VB.NET DLL.
I configure in WEB.config, the connection string for the database.
The problem is that I need to have many copies of this site, each one connecting to a different database. That means, that I have to have one copy of each aspx, one of the dll, etc. for each site, which is a nightmare in terms of actualization, because I need that every site is equal to the others. If I add some functionality to one site a need to update every other. If I have 2 or 3 sites there's no problem but actually I have near 30 and growing.

My idea was to split the site in two: one simple login site per each client which stored the connection string, fill the session variable(including connection string) and then redirect to a single application site, which is the same for each client. But the problem is that is hard (for what I know) to share session objects between sites.

I'm I missing something? is there a better solution for this problem?

Comment: is your database schema the same for each site? can you give us some more information about what these sites are doing so we can suggest what you should do. to me it sounds like you are likely creating more work for yourself and that you could actually be sharing the same db and site

Comment: If you want to keep the databases separated, you can always put all of the connection strings in web config, and tag it with the domain name. Assuming each site is named differently, this would be a relatively simple solution.

Comment: It might be worth thinking about some type of content management system (like Ektron for example). It is much easier to manage that many sites with them, especially if you utilize the synchronization features which can keep these sites in sync.

Comment: The site is a car track system interacting with google maps. I want to maintain the one database per client schema, because some clients have a 3 GB db and others a 2 MB db. Each database schema is exactly the same, except of course for the data in then tables. The solution 2 propose by jTorres sounds interesant, to save all connection strings in one web.config and chose wich to use from domain name (all the sites are avaible from same domain: example: myDomain/Client1, myDomain/Client2, etc). but how do i get the part of the domain name i´m interesing ('Client1' and 'Client2')
Thanks!!!!